# Is there any way to convert a Minecraft Map to Krunker Map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, krunker.io

I've created a lot of *maps* in **minecraft**, and I took a look at how to create *maps* in **krunker**. I found some **similarities** between the two, but I'm not sure if that would make this *conversion* possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no. They use completely different map systems! Right now as of season 3 Krunker has no way to import object files :( Maybe someday though! Krunker has lots of other mapping tools and you could try to remake your minecraft map with the ingame krunker editor!

Answer (score 0):

There may be some ways to do it, albeit backhandedly. First, you would need to convert your minecraft map to a 3D model. Not sure how krunker handles their maps, but I assume they are just model files and textures. Once you have a portion of your minecraft world in model form, you could probably figure out how to import it into krunker.io

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. You can go to  the 'worlds' folder and import all the object and wiremeshes into a 3D editor. Save it as a 3D object and import that into Krunker editor. Place respective spawn, death points etc.

Comment: Seems as his is a very hard thing too do